# node.js regex extracting occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this regex...

```
/user/([A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Which is matched to this input string...

```
/user/me
```

Which brings this result in console...

```
['/user/me', 'me', index: 0, input: '/user/me']
```

Also see this example...

```
Regex: /user/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/([A-Za-z0-9]*)
Input: /user/me/you
Result: ['/user/me/you', 'me', 'you', index: 0, input: '/user/me/you']
```

First result just returns **me** but second returns **me** and **you**, is there a built-in function in node.js that will extract these occurrences or I would need to loop through this array with conditions?

Comment: I had a mistake in question. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Array.slice`:

```
results=mystring.match(myregex).slice(1);
```

Comment: don't you think this will just bring "me" and what if arguments are mo re than one?

Comment: I tried it myself with your second example, and it certainly came back with `['me', 'you']`. Remember that if you omit the second argument to `slice` it means "to the end of the array".

Comment: You seems right. Why named items like index and input won't come out?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node are you using? The result of matching `/user/me/you` seems unreasonable. Anyway, I run code below on Node.js 0.8.4

```
> r = /\/user\/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/
  /\/user\/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/
> r.exec('/user/me')
  [ '/user/me',
    'me',
    index: 0,
    input: '/user/me' ]
> r.exec('/user/me/you')
  [ '/user/me',
    'me',
    index: 0,
    input: '/user/me/you' ]
```

Comment: I am using <string>.match(<string>);

Comment: I had a mistake in question. Fixed it.